# How to convince the typechecker that the types in the where clause match the toplevel type?

Tags: idris

I'm trying to convince the type checker that the type specified in the where clause matches one of the types of the top level function.

For example:

```
interface SomeInterface (e: Type -> Type) where
  label : e l -> l

f : (SomeInterface e) => e l -> c
f x = ?hole_f
  where
    g : e l
    g = ?hole_g
```

The type of `?hole_g` should be `e l`, but the typechecker is unable to match the `l` type in `g : e l` to the `l` type in the toplevel `f : (SomeInterface e) => e l -> c` type. So according to the typechecker the type of `?hole_g` is `e l1`

One way to fix this is to include `l` as a separate type variable in the toplevel function `f`, like this:

```
f : (SomeInterface e) => e l -> l -> c
f x _ = ?hole_f
  where
    g : e l
    g = ?hole_g
```

Notice that the `l` in the toplevel function is completely neglected due to the `_`. But the typechecker is now somehow convinced that the type variable of `?hole_g` is `e l`, like the toplevel type.

My two questions are: 
1) Why is the typechecker unable to "link" the types of function `g` to `f`? 
2) How can i fix this without including an extra type variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f : (SomeInterface e) => e l -> c
f x {l} = ?hole_f_1
  where
    g : e l
    g = ?hole_g
```

Does this do what you want? I believe since `e l` is a type, you can still get the implicit information about the `l` part.